# Git push problem : Unable to find remote helper for 'ttps'

Tags: linux, git, github, terminal

[image: WSL TERMINAL]

When I Try to push my local folder to **Git** I get this error : Unable to find remote helper for 'ttps'.
I'm using WSL terminal. Have you any suggestions to settle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run following command :

```
git remote get-url origin
```

You must get something like :

```
ttps://github.com/...
```

So you can fix it by :

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your already existing origin remote is malformed, you can check with `git remote -v`. If it is, you can remove it with `git remote rm origin`, and then add your current one.

Comment: Relatively minor: generally you don't want to remove-and-add, but rather to use `git remote set-url` instead. This keeps you remote-tracking names intact. In the OP's case, though, his `git remote add` *failed* and he may not be dealing with this general case at all.